# same name in bilevel partition d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bilevel partition on d3.js following the example :
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5944371
In the data, if I have two elements having the same name on the same level, one will be blank and will not be drawn in the chart.
Do you please have any idea how to make it possible to have two elements having the same name appear on the same level ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score -2):

I ended up with a workaround by adding a code to the name to have always distinct names however it would be good to allow different names after all the element can have other properties ..

Comment: You need to have more info about how data binding works in d3 and what are key functions. 

Visit this link - https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/#key-functions